# Show the inequality $x <y$ is definable in the language $\langle \mathbb{R}; +, \times ; 0,1 \rangle $

Tags: logic, model-theory

My initial idea is that I need to find a sentence that expresses 'x is positive' and then I can say: for any $a, b$,  $a>b$ iff there is a positive x s.t. $b+x=a$, but can't figure out how, any ideas?

Or am I going about this the wrong way?

Thanks!

Comment: http://thenumerist.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/parabola-graph.jpg $\;$

Comment: oh yeah, that is very obvious, I was thinking far too complicated- thanks @RickyDemer

Answer (score 2):

A real number is positive exactly if it is a square and not zero.